# Import shortcut does not work after installing STS

Tags: java, eclipse

Import shortcut does not work after installing STS
Is there any way to solve it? (Ctrl + shift + O)

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Menu go to *Windows*->*Preferences*-> *General* -> *keys* then sort by `binding` and verify that your new pluging in not braking the old shortcuts

[image]

Comment: Preferences - general - key
It is set up properly.

In Preferences - Java - Save Actions, check the Organize imports checkbox

When you save the document and save it (Ctrl + S), import will be normal.

All other shortcuts work well. No import shortcuts.
 
Key Setting value File import setting after importing does not work even import.

Comment: After importing the STS, the import was working normally.

After you install Eclipse, it will work before you install the STS in the marketplace, but not after the installation.

I do not know what you mean. I am Korean. Can you tell me a little bit more?

(Verify that your new plug-in does not braking the old shortcuts)

Comment: I agree. The keyboard shortcuts are listed in the settings but actually typing them has no effect. This issue is new since the last update to STS 3.9.0 on Eclipse 4.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. Click the "Filters..." button on the "Keys" page and uncheck all.
2. Enter "ctrl+shift+o" to search the command list for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.
3. You can see the command list, and then unbind commands other than "Organize Imports".
4. Click "Apply".